# AndroidManifest is givin me multiple error

Tags: android, flutter, intellij-idea, android-manifest

I am having multiple error regarding following AndroidManifest.xml
these are the error.
I am flutter bigginer, and couldn't understand reading similer posts.

・Attribute android:usesCleartextTraffic is not allowed here

・Attribute android:icon is not allowed here

・Unresolved class 'MainActivity'

・Attribute android:launchMode is not allowed here

・Attribute android:theme is not allowed here

・Attribute android:configChanges is not allowed here

・Attribute android:hardwareAccelerated is not allowed here

・Attribute android:windowSoftInputMode is not allowed here

What I have tried so far is invalidate cache and remove all of them and re-add lines.
Do you know what is to be fixed? this code below is renewed version after two kind people gave me coments:)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.packagename">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <application android:label="@string/activity_name" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
          <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
          <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
          </intent-filter>
          <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2"/>
        </activity>
      </application>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest should look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- Beware that these values are overridden by the build.gradle file -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- This name is resolved to com.example.myapp.MainActivity
             based upon the namespace property in the `build.gradle` file -->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Unfortunately you have placed most of your property in disarray

Comment: Thank you for your responce. I really appreciated. Do you mean manifest > having application > having activity > having meta-data / intent-filter by code above??   I added <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> on top and set like <application><activity><metadata/><metadata/><intent-filter><action/><category/><intent.../><metadata/><activity/></application><manifest/> and got rid of applicationName .... still errors remain.